# Get phone location using GPS

Tags: android, service, gps, location, broadcastreceiver

Hey I am trying to get a phone location using **GPS** and I tried this code but it doesn't show anything (I am running it on the simulator and changing the location there) but it seems that it doesn't even enter the location change method..

Here is the activity code:

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(broadcastReceiver==null)
    {

        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"cor",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             //   Log.d("cors:",""+intent.getExtras().get("cordinates"));
            }
        };
    }
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,new IntentFilter("location_update"));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(broadcastReceiver!=null)
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    Log.d("oncraet","oncreate");
    setSize();
    if(!runtime_permissions())
    {
        enable_buttons();
    }


}
private boolean runtime_permissions() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}
                ,100);
        return  true;
    }
    return  false;
}

public void enable_buttons()
{
    Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GPS_Service.class);
    startService(i);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 100) {

        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            enable_buttons();

        } else {

            runtime_permissions();

        }
    }
}
```

and here is the Service class code:

```
public class GPS_Service extends Service {



    private LocationListener listener;

    private LocationManager locationManager;



    @Nullable

    @Override

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return null;

    }



    @Override

    public void onCreate() {



        listener = new LocationListener() {

            @Override

            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                Intent i = new Intent("location_update");

                i.putExtra("coordinates",location.getLongitude()+" "+location.getLatitude());

                sendBroadcast(i);

            }



            @Override

            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {



            }



            @Override

            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {



            }



            @Override

            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);

                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                startActivity(i);

            }

        };



        locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);



        //noinspection MissingPermission

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,3000,0,listener);



    }



    @Override

    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();

        if(locationManager != null){

            //noinspection MissingPermission

            locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);

        }

    }

    }
```

the manifest is all good..
what is the problem? and how can I make the app get the first location without it has to move first?

Answer (score 0):

look at my example here

```
    private LocationManager locationManager;
private double lastKnownStartLatitude, lastKnownStartLongtitude;

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(serviceString);


            String serviceString = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
                        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(serviceString);

                        String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            return;
                        }

            // if lastKnownLocation is not null 
                        lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                        if (lastKnownLocation != null) {
                            lastKnownStartLatitude = lastKnownLocation.getLatitude();
                            lastKnownStartLongtitude = lastKnownLocation.getLongitude();
                        }

                 // if lastKnownLocation is  null 
                        LocationListener myLocationListener = new LocationListener() {

                            public void onLocationChanged(Location locationListener) {


                                Location location;


                             // using gps
                                if (isGPSEnabled(YourClassName.this)) {
                                    if (locationListener != null) {
                                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(YourClassName.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(TestWithLocationListener.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                                            return;
                                        }
                                        System.out.println("Hello isGPSEnabled");
                                        if (locationManager != null) {
                                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                                            if (location != null) {
                                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else if (isInternetConnected(TestWithLocationListener.this)) {
                                    if (locationManager != null) {
                                        location = locationManager
                                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                                        if (location != null) {
                                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Google's [fused location provider API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi)  as it is now the new best practice to fetch location.

You get updates for best location available from all sources according to your location request.

[This](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) tutorial on developer's site  is really good.